# can readCalibrationIni function get ROI data parsing a file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody, I'm building a simple application that read a file .txt, parse it with

```
bool readCalibrationIni(const std::string& file_name, std::string& camera_name,
                        sensor_msgs::CameraInfo& cam_info)
```

of "camera_calibration_parsers" package
and create an object "sensor_msgs::CameraInfo".
This function seems don't parse ROI (Region Of Interest) info contained in the file, for example:

```
# Camera intrinsics
[image]

width
640

height
480

[TrusCamera]

camera matrix
782.015630 0.000000 347.626583
0.000000 785.621477 155.819230
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

distortion
-0.153979 -0.023735 -0.002647 0.002344 0.000000

rectification
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

projection
757.675406 0.000000 349.847926 0.000000
0.000000 765.347350 152.545843 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000

[roi]
x_offset
0

y_offset
0

height
0

width
0

do_rectify
False
```

parsing this file the following fields are filled in the CameraInfo object:

```
CameraInfo_()
  : header()
  , height(0)
  , width(0)
  , distortion_model()
  , D()
  , K()
  , R()
  , P()
```

but not the fields related to ROI and binning

```
, binning_x(0)
  , binning_y(0)
  , roi()
  {
    K.assign(0.0);
    R.assign(0.0);
    P.assign(0.0);
  }
```

How to set them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45097/can-readcalibrationini-function-get-roi-data-parsing-a-file?/) by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. The ROI and binning are operational parameters, separate from the intrinsic calibration.

EDIT: Those fields are set to zeros by the `CameraInfo` constructor. Clients interpret that as "no binning" and "full resolution ROI".

If you want to set them yourself, store the desired values in the corresponding variables. [REP 104](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0104.html#operational-parameters) explains their semantics.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on 2012-10-08**:
Thank you @joq, Is there any "readOperationalParameters" function available in another package?

**Comment by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on 2012-10-09**:
Yes,it seems work. I did creating a sensor_msgs::CameraInfo camera_info by  readCalibrationIni and I filled camera_info.roi.x_offset=... and all the others field. Kind regards.